# Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840について

Tags: swift, php, json, swift3

swift3.0でJSONを解析したいのですが下記のエラーが出てしまい困っています。
swift、PHPともに勉強中ですのでまだ理解してない部分も多いです。
このような説明で大変申し訳ないのですが、ご教示お願いいたします。

> Error  43-> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

以下ソースコードになります。
.swift

```
let array = ["data=文字列"]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error 55 -> \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                print("Result 34 -> \(result)")
            } catch {
                print("Error  43-> \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

.php

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: 3840と言うのはパラメータエラー一般を表すのであまり役に立たないのですが、`JSONSerialization`でそのエラーが出た場合、ほぼ間違いなくデータがJSONとして受け付けられないようなものになっています。あなたのコードの場合、SwiftからパラメータをJSONとして送信する部分も、PHP側でそれをJSONとして受け取る部分も間違っているので、応答がPHPのエラー応答(HTML)になってしまい、JSONとしては不正なデータであることから受信後の`try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)`が表題のエラーを発生しているものと思われます。その行の前に`print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))`なんて行を追加すれば、サーバ側からどんな応答が返ってきているかを確認できるはずですので、お試しください。(サーバの設定によっては、`String.Encoding.utf8`を別のエンコーディングにしないとnilしか表示されないかも知れません。)「PHPでJSONデータを受信する」あたりで検索すれば、PHP側でのやり方はすぐに出てきますので、少なくともそちらは自分の力で解決する(と言っても送信側を直さないと確かめられませんが…)ようにしてみてください。

Comment: @LePered'OO "応答がPHPのエラー応答(HTML)になってしまい" とありますが、再現できませんでした。また、"SwiftからパラメータをJSONとして送信する部分"の間違いが何を指しているのかわかりませんでした。

Comment: @quesera2 さん、 エラー応答についてはこちらのテスト環境ではPHPのエラー出力を常時オンにしているので、いつでもそれが送信されるかのような書き方は勘違いで、まずかったですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。「"SwiftからパラメータをJSONとして送信する部分"の間違い」については、送信パラメータを"application/json"として送ろうとしていることが大前提です。この言い方でわからなければ「SwiftでJSONを送信するにはどうすれば良いのか？」と言うところを調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quesera2 さんのご回答にあるように「Swift 側と PHP 側のロジックが噛み合っていない」のが問題ですので、本来はご質問者にどの部分が必須でどの部分は必須でないのかをきちんと明らかにしていただいてから答えるのが筋かと思うのですが、一つの想定としてこんな感じになりますと言うのを例としてあげておきます。

- 送信データは"application/json"として送信したい
- サーバ側では(動作確認用に)受信したデータを丸ごと返したいだけ
- サーバ側ではJSON内の'data'要素を(必要であれば)とり出せるようにしておきたいが今は不要

と言うわけで、まずは**Swift側**から:

```
    let jsonObject = ["data": "文字列"]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/test.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error 55 -> \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                print("Result 34 -> \(result)")
            } catch {
                print("Error  43-> \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

- 送信するデータを`array = ["data=文字列"]`から`jsonObject = ["data": "文字列"]`と変更してありますが、これはあまり本質的ではありません。

上記の2つめの条件の「サーバ側では(動作確認用に)受信したデータを丸ごと返したいだけ」と言うのがありならば、Swift側では`NSArray`か`NSDictionary`に変換可能なデータであれば良いと言うことになります。ご質問にあるコードでも(下記のPHP側の修正をすれば)正しく送受信できます。

- 送信時の"Content-Type"の設定は一度で良いので、2つ目は省略
- NSURLRequest, NSURLの使い方については、quesera2さんの回答の注意点の通りです

続いて**PHP側**

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($json_string);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

上記のSwift側の方法で送信されたデータは、HTTPリクエストのボディ部全体にJSONのテキスト表現を表すバイトデータが埋め込まれる形で送信されることになり、PHPが`$_POST`として解釈可能な、"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"にも"multipart/form-data"にもなっていません。そのような場合、自前でHTTPリクエストのボディ部を読み込んで、それをJSONとして解釈する必要があります。上記の最初の2行がそれをやるコードで、3行目と4行目はそれをもう一度"application/json"として丸ごと返しているだけです。

一つの回答にするには、あれやこれや盛り込みすぎですので、少々わかりにくいかも知れませんが、最初に書いたような前提を置くとこのようなコードが書けますと言うことでお受け取りください。もし少々の修正でご質問者さんの想定通りの動きをさせられそうであれば、ご質問を修正くださるか、コメント等でお知らせください。

Answer (score 0):

Swift 側と PHP 側のロジックが噛み合っていないです。

Swift 側では、リクエストとして `["data=文字列"]` という JSON を送信しています。

一方、PHP 側では、`$_POST['data']` を受け取ろうとしていますが、こちらはフォームの `data` 要素を取得するものです。ですので、これは必ず空値になります。

- `$_POST`変数には何が格納されるのか？
- PHP で JSON 本文を受け取るにはどうすればいいのか？

というところを調べてみてください。

---

Swift 側だけで対応しようとすると、こんな感じです。

```
let data = "文字列"

guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/test.php") else {
   return
}
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = "data=\"\(data)\"".data(using: .utf8)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = URLSession.shared().dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in

   if let error = error {
       print("Error 55 -> \(error)")
       return
   }

   if let data = data {
       do {
           let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
           print("Result 34 -> \(result)")
       } catch {
           print("Error  43-> \(error)")
       }
   }           
}
task.resume()
```

いくつか注意点です。

- `"[data=文字列]"` を JSON にした場合、 `data=文字列` という文字列を要素に持つ、単一の配列になります。おそらく意図しているところは、`{data:"文字列"}` という連想配列ではないでしょうか。
- Swift3 では、`NSURL` クラスではなく、`URL` 構造体を使うことが望ましいです。不要な型変換がなくなります。
- 同じく、`NSMutableURLRequest` クラスではなく、 `URLRequest` 構造体を使ってください。`Mutable` であることを示すために、`var` で宣言します。
- PHP 側の仕様に合わせて、フォームとして値を送信する処理に変更しています。
- サーバーから返却される JSON のルート要素は、「文字列」という `String` になりますが、`JSONSerialization` はデフォルトではルート要素が配列もしくはオブジェクトしか受け付けません。もしルート要素が `String` となるような JSON を受信したい場合には、`.allowFragments` のオプションが必要になります。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。表示することができました。もう一つ質問で申し訳ないのですが結果をtextviewに表示したい    self.textview.text = "\(result)"    実行時に    Assertion failure in void,Terminating app due to uncaught exception    が出てしまします。どのように改良したらいいでしょうか？

Comment: `URLSession`の結果の受信処理はバックグラウンドスレッドで行われているので、そこから`textview`に表示したい場合、 `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textview.text = "(result)" }` という感じでメインスレッドで行う必要があるのかと思います。